# Document has no root element exception using simple xml serializer (v2.6.6)

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-serialization

I'm using simple xml library http://simple.sourceforge.net/ to deserialize an object from a socket input stream.
While in simple java application the same situation works fine, in android I get, after

```
MyObject obj = serializer.read(MyObject.class,socket.getInputStream())
```

> org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeException: Document has no root
>   element

why is that??

Comment: My guess is that you haven't actually got any data coming, but it's hard to know without any more information.

Comment: Data is actually coming: in the java application I'm doing pretty much the same thing.

Comment: If you read directly from the stream and dump it out to a log, what does it look like?

Comment: i am facing same problem .. did u find solution

Answer (score 1):

You haven't been receiving the data. Try to set a Log and check if the data is present or no

Answer (score 0):

Since my last post here was deleted heres my xml again:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<masterclass>
    <question className="Cosmos">
        <body>What year was the first step on the Moon?</body>
        <answer valid="0">1972</answer>
        <answer valid="0">1971</answer>
        <answer valid="0">1970</answer>
        <answer valid="1">1969</answer>
    </question>
    <question className="Cosmos">
        <body>Who were the first men to walk on the Moon?</body>
        <answer valid="1">Neil Armstrong</answer>
        <answer valid="0">Michael Collins</answer>
        <answer valid="0">Eugene Cernan</answer>
        <answer valid="1">Edwin Aldrin</answer>
    </question>
    <question className="History">
        <body>When did Christening of Poland took place?</body>
        <answer valid="0">1025</answer>
        <answer valid="1">966</answer>
        <answer valid="0">866</answer>
        <answer valid="0">916</answer>
    </question>
    <question className="Math">
        <body>Stone weighs 2kg and half stone. How much stone weighs?</body>
        <answer valid="0">2.5kg</answer>
        <answer valid="0">3kg</answer>
        <answer valid="1">4kg</answer>
        <answer valid="0">5kg</answer>
    </question>
</masterclass>
```

And heres code for unmarshall xml file

```
// download successed
try {
    Serializer xmlSer = new Persister();
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xmlFilePath);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"));
    MasterClass mc = xmlSer.read(MasterClass.class, in);
    MasterClass mc = xmlSer.read(MasterClass.class, str);
    Toast.makeText(context.get(), ""+mc.getQuestionList().size(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception ee) {
    Log.e("MasterClass", "xml serialize problem", ee);
}
```

The error was in this line:

```
MasterClass mc = xmlSer.read(MasterClass.class, in);
```

When changed to this:

```
String str = "", s;
while((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
    str += s;
    //Log.d("MasterClass", str);
}
MasterClass mc = xmlSer.read(MasterClass.class, str);
```

It started working.
Not sure why tho... but from my research, it may be related to how the file was saved on device:

```
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8"));
br.write(content);
br.flush();
br.close();
```

And xml file encoding - set to UTF-8 without BOM in notepad++.

To mods: Not sure how to delete so Please delete my question below, tks :)